# Vue3 Vuex state change not updating computed value

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex, vuejs3

I've run into a conundrum where a state change doesn't trigger a computed value in my component to update. I have a Finder component mapping 2 state values: vehicle `makes`, and `models`, which requires a `make` to be selected by the user. In short, the user selects a make which correctly triggers the `getModels` action, however, the computed `modelsForMake` property gets recalled **before** the store updates the models via `addModelsForMake`.

I've tried only to include the necessary code to understand the situation, and an FYI, I'm using Nuxt so I don't have composition API access.

```js
export default {
  
  beforeCreate() {
    …
    // Loads models for user to load from
    this.$store.dispatch('vehicle/getMakes');
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapState('vehicle', ['makes', 'models']),

    make: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.vehicle.make;
      },
      set(val) {
        this.$store.commit('vehicle/setMake', val);
      }
    }

    model: //…similar as make…

    // Gets called after state has updated the make and before models get loaded
    modelsForMake() {
      return this.models[this.make] || [];
    },
  },
  watch: {
    make() {
      // Initial trigger: user selected make -> loads models
      this.$store.dispatch('vehicle/getModels', this.make);
    },
  }
  …
}
```

Here's my Vuex store

```js
export const state = () => ({
  make: '',
  model: '',
  makes: [],
  models: {},
});

export const mutations = {
  setMake(state, make: string) {
    Object.assign(state, { make });
  },

  …,

  // This gets called after the computed value updated and it doesn't trigger a recompute
  addModelsForMake(state, models: object[]) {
    if (!models.length) {
      return;
    }

    const obj = {};
    obj[models[0].make_slug] = models
    Object.assign(state.models, obj);
    // Below is the previous Vue2 fix I'm trying to fix
    // Vue.set(state.models, models[0].make_slug, models)
  },
  …
}
export const actions = {
  getModels({ commit, state }, make) {
    if (state.models[make] || make === null) {
      return Promise.resolve();
    }

    return AXIOS_API.get(`/makes/${make}`)
      .then(response => commit('addModelsForMake', response.data)) // models loaded
      .catch(err =>
        console.error(`Failed to get models from the vehicle API: ${err}`)
      );
  },
  …
}
```

Edit: As per @Daniel's response, I tried replacing Object.assign with a direct definition and the same order mismatch occurs

```js
addModelsForMake(state, models: object[]) {
    if (!models.length) {
      return;
    }

    state.models = state.models || {};
    state.models[models[0].make_slug] = models;
}
```

Comment: is `make` an object or a string?

Comment: Yes, `make`: `string`, `models`:`object[]`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```js
  setMake(state, make) {
    state.make = make
  },
```

instead of

```js
  setMake(state, make) {
    Object.assign(state, { make });
  },
```

I think you may be getting into an issue where Vue cannot detect the change because `Object.assign` mutates the first parameter. Given that the first parameter is the same, a change is not detected. Another option, if you want to use `Object.assign` is to pass an empty object first, which will reassign a new object to `state` which should trigger the update also.

```js
  setMake(state, make) {
    state = Object.assign({}, state, { make });
  },
```